# Trouble with Xlsxwriter formatting a pandas DataFrame output to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I've created a pandas pivot_table and exported it to excel with xlsxwriter. However, the formatting is not doing what I think I'm telling it to do. I've looked at the xlsxwriter docs and at other questions here on Stack Overflow and I haven't found a solution. I have a feeling I'm overlooking something obvious.

```
# Write to Excel
path = 'some/path'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df')
```

The column widths with `set_column()` are working. So I've got that going for me, which is nice. But the `'bold': False` and `'align': 'left'` in the `wb.add_format()` clause are not.

```
# Make it look nice
wb = writer.book
ws = writer.sheets['df']

format = wb.add_format({'bold': False,
                        'align': 'left'})
ws.set_column('A:C', None, format)

ws.set_column(0,0, 10.2)
ws.set_column(1,1, 25.2)
ws.set_column(2,2, 15.2)

writer.save()
```

Alternatively, the following does apply the formatting but it deletes the contents of cell B3:

```
ws.write('B3', None, format)
```

Can I make my columns align left and not bold?

---

UPDATE:
I've upgraded to pandas 17.0 and I've updated my code to this:

```
format_bold = wb.add_format({'bold': False})
format_and_left = wb.add_format({'align': 'left', 'bold': False})

ws.set_column('A:A', 10.2, format_bold)
ws.set_column('B:B', 25.2, format_and_left)
ws.set_column('C:C', 15.2, format_bold)
```

Still no luck. I've confirmed that my interpreter is using pandas version 0.17.0 by using `print pd.__version__`. Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: Which version of Pandas are you using? [This was a known issue before Pandas 16](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/204)

Comment: Tried updating with conda. Having some issues importing pandas now. I'll check back in once I've completed the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jkdc points out it is worth ensuring that you are using Pandas 16+ since there was an XlsxWriter `set_column` issue in earlier versions.

However, there is also an issue in your code where you are overriding the `set_column()` properties for columns `A:C` which has a format with other calls for columns `A`, `B` and `C` which don't:

```
ws.set_column('A:C', None, format)

ws.set_column(0,0, 10.2)
ws.set_column(1,1, 25.2)
ws.set_column(2,2, 15.2)
```

Something like the following should probably work (unless there are other issues):

```
ws.set_column(0, 0, 10.2, format)
ws.set_column(1, 1, 25.2, format)
ws.set_column(2, 2, 15.2, format)
```

Also note, [as outlined in the documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_pandas.html) this won't work for datetime columns. For those you will have to use the Pandas API to specify the formatting and that is limited to setting the number format.

Comment: I was indeed using an old version. I'll check back in once I've troubleshooted my update. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @jmcnamara, somehow the columns still show up bold and centered. I appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Hold on. If I'm trying to override the formatting done by a pd.pivot_table on the index columns am I already not supposed to do that?

Comment: You cannot override the heading or index formats using Pandas.

Comment: Great, I think that answers my question. Thanks for the help!